# React: Traversing nested Objects in state to prevent duplicates – most performant way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React component, I have a state object that looks like this:

```
this.state = {
    items: [
        { id: 1, title: 'foo' },
        { id: 2, title: 'bar' },
        { id: 3, title: 'baz' }
    ]
};
```

When adding a new item, I want to prevent duplicates, so I need to check if an item with that title already exists.

To do that, I am required to iterate over the `items` array and check the new item's title against each single one. I am not quite sure about this, but this seems to be a pretty expensive task. What is the most performant way to do this inside a React component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If `title` is unique, save your items in an object** with `title` as a key. Then you can simply do;

```
if (!items[title]) {
    items = Object.assign({}, items, {
        [title]: newEntry
    });
}
```

**If you must have an array of objects** like you have in example, then I would use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which does the following:

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

Then you can check the title of each object in the array very easily as follows;

```
items.find( ( object ) => {
    return object.title === testCase;
});
```

If your `testCase` is in the array it will return its value, or `undefined` if it is not found.

**If you don't need the value of `testCase` returned**, You could use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

> The findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Is performance an issue when using a simple [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)?

```
var alreadyPresent = this.state.items.some(itm => id === someId);
```

If it's not a performance issue, and unless you have alot of items, it probably won't be, don't worry about it and use the most easily readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose `Array#find` for it.

```
if (!this.state.items.find(v => v.title == objToAdd.title)) {
  this.setState({ items: this.state.items.concat(objToAdd) });
}
```